# Replace the last element of the list-of-list

Tags: python

I have a list likes this:

```
myList = [[1, 'A1', 100, '1001', '1', '1001', 'None'],
          [2, 'B1', 101, '3008', '2', '3008', 'bb'],
          [3, 'C1', 102, '607', '3', '607', 'None']]
```

I want to replace the last element in every sublist.

If the last element in every sublist is 'None',replace 'None' with ' '.

The list should like this:

```
myList = [[1, 'A1', 100, '1001', '1', '1001', ' '],
          [2, 'B1', 101, '3008', '2', '3008', 'bb'],
          [3, 'C1', 102, '607', '3', '607', ' ']]
```

Comment: you may use this also list(map(lambda x:x[:-1]+[''] if x[-1]=='None' else x,myList))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative index.

**Ex:**

```
myList = [[1, 'A1', 100, '1001', '1', '1001', 'None'],
          [2, 'B1', 101, '3008', '2', '3008', 'bb'],
          [3, 'C1', 102, '607', '3', '607', 'None']]

myList = [i[:-1] + [""] if i[-1] == 'None' else i for i in myList ]
print(myList)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 'A1', 100, '1001', '1', '1001', ''],
 [2, 'B1', 101, '3008', '2', '3008', 'bb'],
 [3, 'C1', 102, '607', '3', '607', '']]
```

Comment: This is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use negative indexing:

```
for subList in myList:
    if subList[-1] == 'None':
        subList[-1] = ' '
myList
# [[1, 'A1', 100, '1001', '1', '1001', ' '],
#  [2, 'B1', 101, '3008', '2', '3008', 'bb'],
#  [3, 'C1', 102, '607', '3', '607', ' ']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = [[1, 'A1', 100, '1001', '1', '1001', 'None'],[2, 'B1', 101, '3008', '2', '3008', 'bb'],[3, 'C1', 102, '607', '3', '607', 'None']]

for i in range(len(myList)):
    print(i)
    print(type(myList[i][len(myList[i])-1]))
    if(myList[i][len(myList[i])-1]== 'None'):
        myList[i][len(myList[i])-1]=' '
print(myList)
```

Comment: please provide an explanation. would be helpful for others.